# VBScript throws an error

Tags: vbscript, windows-task-scheduler

I am writing a VBScript to schedule a task which will delete log files from a specific location I am using an error handler and getting

> error 76

which I think is path not found error.

```
sCommand = "SchTasks.exe /create  /RU " & sScheduledTaskUser & " /RP " & sScheduledTaskPassword & " /SC Daily /TN " & chr(34) & "DeleteLog" & Chr(34) & " /TR " & chr(128) & "forfiles /P ""C:\winstore\logs"" /S /C ""cmd /c del @path""" & Chr(34) & " /ST " & sNextDeleteTime & " /SD " & sNextDeleteDate
```

The command for deleting files is

```
forfiles /P "C:\winstore\logs" /S /C "cmd /c del @path"
```

Comment: `Chr(128)` -> `Chr(34)`?

Comment: Tried it does not works

Comment: iReturn = oWShell.Run(sCommand,7,True)
  If iReturn <> 0 Then
    LogDetail(sTab & "ERROR! An error " & iReturn & " occurred while re-creating the new task.")
    bCriticalErrors = True
  End If

Comment: I log my errors like metioned above.When i check my log files i get  ERROR! An error -2147467259 occurred while re-creating the new task.

Comment: Are you getting the error when you *create* the task or when you *run* the task? And that appears to be a different error than before.

Comment: I have solved it.The command used is- sCommand = "schtasks /create /sc daily /TN DeleteLog /F /TR "& Chr(34) & "forfiles /P " &Chr(39)& "C:\winstore\logs"&Chr(39)& " /S /C "&Chr(39) &"cmd /c del @path"&Chr(39)&Chr(34) & " /ST " & sNextDeleteTime & " /SD " & sNextDeleteDate